# Xcode 4 Download

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I just downloaded XCode 4 on my new Mac running 10.6.7 and I don't see an XCode application. I just see a folder that it created in /Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/Library.

I'm trying to develop for iOS and I had it installed on my previous machine. Why didn't the install create an app? I don't see XCode in Applications?

Oh, and the installation completed successfully with the green checkmark when I installed it.

Comment: cmd+space open spotlight and search for xcode4. Its a long an arduous install and if anything interupts it then you'll have to go through it again!

Comment: Look in /Developer/Applications or use Spotlight.

Comment: check in  /XCODE4.0/Applications/xcode

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I too don't have XCode in my Applications folder.

It is instead in /Developer/Applications, I just drag that down to the dock and access it from there.